# Alamofire does not work

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have written a ios program which has used Almofire for REST, for a part of the app, I need to send a POST request to the server and get JSON, Alamofire send request correctly and server response to the app but Almofire does not show the response, actually in the code below, compiler never run "print(Result)" even the server response correctly, why? ( in code, comments are not in English! )

```
  Alamofire.request(urlString, method:HTTPMethod.post , parameters:    parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:headers).responseJSON
  { Result in

            // (responseData) -> Void in
                print(Result)
                if((Result.result.value) != nil)
                {
                    //data ra be value tabdil mikonad
                    let ResValue = JSON(Result.result.value!)
                    print(ResValue)

                    //check mikone ke aya key be name access_token vojod dare ya na
                    if   ( ResValue["error"].exists() )
                    {
                        //agar token expire shode bud
                        if (ResValue["error"] == "Authorization Required")
                        {

                            let pass = keychain.get("password")
                            //initial kardan class marbut be function get token
                            let get = LoginAndRegistration()

                            //estefade az function get token
                            get.getToken(userName:userName,passWord:pass!)
                            { results in
                                //agar gereftan token taiid shod
                                if results == "token got!"
                                {
                                    //gereftan data
 Alamofire.request(urlString,method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"JWT \(token)"]).responseJSON
                                        { response in

                                            //agar data vojod dasht
                                            if((response.result.value) != nil)
                                            {
                                                //data ra be value tabdil mikonad
                                                let responseValue = JSON(response.result.value!)
                                                //enteghal  data be dakhel tabe khanandeh
                                                //self.hairdressShow(json: responseValue)
                                                DataRe(responseValue)
                                            }

                                    }

                                }
                                    //agar token jadid ham daryaft nashod
                                else
                                {
                                    //seque be login page

                                    //DataRe((["test"] as AnyObject) as! Array<Any>,1,1)

                                    // DataRe(["message":"seque"])
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    //agar value "Data" vojod dasht, yani hamechi ok !
                    if ( ResValue["Data"].exists() )
                    {

                        //self.hairdressShow(json: ResValue)
                        DataRe(ResValue)


                    }

                    else
                    {

                        //  DataRe(["message":"Something's Wrong"])

                    }

                }
            }.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "result" instead of "Result"? I think that Alamofire is using the enum Result, not the variable you want, that's why it's coloured like a class. I don't know if this is going to solve your problem, but you can try.

Variables always in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
   print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")// original url request
   print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))")// http url response
   print("Result: \(response.result)")// response serialization result

   if let json = response.result.value {
       print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
   }
}
```

Here is the documentation: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#http-methods